# Extract form only from modelform without instance logic

Tags: django, forms, modelform

Is there an obvious way to convert a `ModelForm` into a regular `Form` without the instance setting logic?

I have an Update/Create ModelForm View I'd like to convert into a `SearchView` by using input from the exact same list of fields to query the model but it causes problems with required fields and types since the `ModelForm` attaches data to `self.instance` immediately.

I've ended up hacking into the metaclass to get what I want but I feel like I could easily be missing some solution right before my eyes overriding some function. I don't really enjoy pulling core django code...

Other forms of hackery would be preferable to copy and pasting the entire metaclass.

```
class ModelFormMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        formfield_callback = attrs.pop('formfield_callback', None)
        try:
            parents = [b for b in bases if issubclass(b, ModelToForm)] #<-- here
        # ... rest of class

class ModelToForm(BaseForm):
    __metaclass__ = ModelFormMetaclass
```

Update:

It appears `ModelForm._post_clean()` is responsible for instance construction / related field validation.

Currently I'm disabling `_post_clean()` and seeing where that takes me.

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem with just using it as-is? Unless you specify an instance when instantiating the form, `self.instance` is merely an empty object.

Comment: If all you want is a `Form` without the things that make it a `ModelForm`...why not just use a `Form`? What do you need your form to do?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I'm not sure what my problem was at all now... I thought I was having issues with the instance not accepting certain search values.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ah yes, overriding `_post_clean` allows me to bypass `ModelForm` instance validation: `construct_instance` does validation and prevents *not null related fields* from ever being passed `None`. This is a search form, so I'm converting my C/U ModelForm to become "all fields optional".

Comment: If you just want to make everything optional, override the form's `__init__` and loop through `self.fields.iterkeys()`. Then `self.fields[key].required = False`

Comment: @ChrisPratt - that's not enough because non nullable related fields will immediately complain when `_post_clean` is called. So for now, overriding _post_clean is the solution.